# how to use codefolding feature of notepad++ for normal text documents

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, documents

When I open an reg file in notepad++ file in notepad++, I see the amazing functionality to minimize and maximize the subkeys of a base key by clicking on that little arrow on the left. Can I get this functionality in normal documents? I want to create different categories for ex: topic 1, topic 2, etc, which I can maximize and minimize.

[image: http://imgur.com/JU8JfwF]

Comment: If you click `Language -> Define your language...` you can define code folding styles in the `Folding in code 1 style` boxes. You need to set a symbol which means "open the fold" (maybe "Topic") and a symbol which closes the fold (e.g. "Endtopic"). However, this will mean that you will need to add "Endtopic" to your files, so I'm not sure that this is an ideal solution

Comment: this is amazing , sorry for late reply but your answer worked for me , thanx :)

Comment: Thanks Adi, glad I could help! I've made my comment into an answer - could you please accept it?

Comment: dude , really very sorry for late reply , i had tried to upvote it but couldn't because i don't have enough reputation to tick a reply as answer.maybe someone else who may benefit from it can or i will when i have enough rep ,thanx again , it was working very useful for me ,have a great day

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define your own syntax highlighting and code folding rules by defining a 'User language'. Click `Language -> Define your language...` to open the User Defined Language dialog.

This dialog gives options for many levels of customisation. In your case, you could add the word 'Topic' to the 'Folding in code 1 style' open list.

Comment: thank you it really helped

Comment: @TheTruKey that was an amazing answer, thank yous o much.

Answer (score 8):

Basically, 
View -> User-Defined Dialogue 
Create New. I call it Txt, set the extension to .txt 
In folder and default pane, set the open and close options. 
I use {{ and }} respectively.

Then from the View menu, use the fold, collapse options.

More details in http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/c01d98f7