# Is there a way to perform block folding in CSS with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, css

For example, I wanted to be able to collapse this section block.

```
/* BEGIN FOOTER CSS */

footer {
    padding: 40px 0px 30px 0px !important;
}

div.copyright {
    padding: 60px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

/* END FOOTER CSS */
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

as soon as you change the language to css, you get the collapsing option displayed (at least in v. 6.1.5)...

Comment: I can collapse comments, but not blocks.

Comment: ah, sorry, misunderstood your question: in that case what about this: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages there you can define any "marker" as beginning and/or end of a block (in your case your comment...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are trying to by defining a [user defined language](https://superuser.com/questions/626194/how-to-use-codefolding-feature-of-notepad-for-normal-text-documents).

Go to `Language -> Define your language`.

Under the 'Folding in code 1 style' open list, in the 'Open' box, insert: `///* BEGIN` and in the 'Close' box insert `///* END`.

The reason for the triple forward slashes is that they are escape characters to prevent NP++ from viewing the /* as a regex match (i think - figured that out by experimentation).

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474041/notepad-edit-syntax-highlighting-for-php).

Comment: Won't the ///* cause problems later for the CSS parser?

Comment: No. The actual comments in the CSS will be normal comments. i.e. /* comment */ . The instructions and syntax above apply to settings within NP++, to tell it how to identify normal CSS comments.

Comment: Just to qualify that, "...normal CSS comments..." of the type that you're aiming to use. Where two separate comments will define the beginning and end of a foldable block. So it will only work work with your suggested BEGIN / END syntax.